# RAID Monitoring

Tags: raid

Is there any open source Dell H/w base RAID monitoring tool? Or any tool which monitors the hdd disks failure in RAID or power supply failure on Dell PE servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Dell OpenManage Server Administrator.

Comment: to clarify, it's not Open Source but it's freely available and works fantastically to monitor everything under the sun on your PE servers.

Answer (score 5):

as an administrator of lots of dell hardware, i know how annoying the dell openmanage tools are...
(fail randomly sometimes, are extremly bloated, ...)

luckily, for example, dell's "PERC" raid controllers used in poweredge servers are just rebranded lsi megaraid adapters, and you can use lsi's megacli in place of openmanage:
(which is still closed source, but at least less annoying, or annoying in different ways ;) )

```
# omreport storage pdisk controller=0 | grep -i state # dell openmanage
State                     : Online
State                     : Online
# MegaCli -PDList -a0 |grep state    # lsi megacli
Firmware state: Online
Firmware state: Online
```

(have not verified if this is the correct version, should be the same for all adaptors tho': http://www.lsi.com/storage_home/products_home/internal_raid/megaraid_sas/megaraid_sas_8480e/#Miscellaneous )

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're talking about Linux. If that's the case, please check the Dell OpenManage Wiki at:
http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/hardware

Answer (score 1):

Be careful if you use OMSA with an non-Dell external enclosure; OMSA will indeed report and display the status of the physical drives but in my experience it will ***not*** alert on hardware issues with the enclosure itself... it only seems to do that for Dell-branded JBOD's.

MegaCli should work for this however, eg:

```
[root@ftp1 bin]# MegaCli64 -AdpEventLog -GetEvents -f /tmp/event.log -aALL

Success in AdpEventLog

Exit Code: 0x00
[root@ftp1 bin]# grep Event /tmp/event.log
Adapter: 0 - Number of Events : 13
Event Description: Event log cleared
Event Data:
Event Description: Enclosure PD 1f(c 01/p1) power supply 2 inserted
Event Data:
Event Description: Enclosure PD 1f(c 01/p1) Power supply 2 switched off
Event Data:
Event Description: Enclosure PD 1f(c 01/p1) Power supply 2 cable removed
Event Data:
```

Answer (score 0):

[Smartmontools](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/) will monitor the disks, but I am not sure about the controller.  (I had to monitor device sg0 rather than sda as documented.)

Disk 0:

```
smartctl -a -d megaraid,0 /dev/sg0
```

Disk 1:

```
smartctl -a -d megaraid,1 /dev/sg0
```

I believe this is PERC 4.